# Put x labels on top of bars AND justify it towards the x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to position x labels on a geom_bar so that they are vertical, on top of the bars, and aligned to the bottom of the bars. I have gotten the first two, but not the last.

```
data(mpg)
mpg <- mpg
```

This justifies the text the way I want it (left/bottom aligned)

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=interaction(manufacturer, year), y=hwy, fill=manufacturer)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, color="black") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 5, hjust=0, vjust=-.05))
```

[image: hjust=0]

This places the text higher up so that it covers the bars, but it isn't justified the way I want it, with each label starting at the x-axis.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=interaction(manufacturer, year), y=hwy, fill=manufacturer)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 1, color="black") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 5, hjust=3, vjust=-.05))
```

[image: hjust=3]

I have also played around with margin=margin(#,#,#,#), which I cannot discern any effect from. What else might I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `geom_text` with `stat = "summary"` to add the labels and `scale_y_continuous` to resize the y-axis:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(interaction(manufacturer, year), hwy, 
                fill = manufacturer, label = interaction(manufacturer, year))) +
    geom_col(width = 1, color = "black") + 
    geom_text(stat = 'summary', fun.y = sum, angle = 90, hjust = -.05, size = 2) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 575), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image: plot with labels]

or if you want the text at the bottom of each bar, just set `y` to 0:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(interaction(manufacturer, year), hwy, fill = manufacturer, label = interaction(manufacturer, year))) +
    geom_col(width = 1, color = "black") + 
    geom_text(aes(y = 0), angle = 90, hjust = -.05, size = 2) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 500), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image: plot with labels at bottom]

Comment: awesome, thanks! The latter is what I was looking for.